# Why does my actix-web fail when posting cross-domain on the front end?

Tags: javascript, http, rust, frontend, cors

actix-web server

```
use actix_web::{web, App, HttpServer, HttpResponse};
use serde::{Deserialize,Serialize};

#[actix_web::main] // or #[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let app = move || {
        App::new().configure(test_routes)
    };


    HttpServer::new(app)
    .bind(("127.0.0.1", 7878))?
    .run()
    .await
}

pub fn test_routes(cfg: &mut web::ServiceConfig){
    cfg
        .service(
            web::scope("/test")
                .route("/post",web::post().to(test_post))
                .route("/get", web::get().to(test_get))
        );
}

pub async fn test_post(data: web::Json<MyRequest>) -> HttpResponse {
    println!(
        "{:?}", data.name
    );
    HttpResponse::Ok().append_header(("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*")).json("Hello,world")
}


pub async fn test_get() -> HttpResponse {
    HttpResponse::Ok().append_header(("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*")).json("Hello,world")
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct MyRequest {
    name: String,
}
```

the post js code

```
/*POST*/
        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
        xhr.open("post","http://localhost:7878/test/post",true)

        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
        xhr.onload = function() {
            console.log("success")
        }
        let data = {
            name:"zack"
        }
        xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data))

/*GET*/
        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
        xhr.open("get","http://localhost:7878/test/get",true)

        xhr.onload = function() {
            console.log("success")
        }

        xhr.send()
```

the frontend error message is as follows:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:7878/test/post' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I have try all Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Access-Control-Allow-Credentials, Access-Control-Allow-Methods, Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Expose-Headers
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwWqA.png)

---

thanks @richzilla help, this problem have solved
this is changed code

```
        App::new()
            .wrap(
                Cors::default()
                    // here is cannot fill out *, or else Error: Custom { kind: Other, error: "can not start server service 0" }
                    .allowed_origin("http://localhost:8080")
                    .allowed_methods(vec!["GET", "POST"])
                    .allowed_headers(vec![http::header::AUTHORIZATION, http::header::ACCEPT,http::header::ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN])
                    .allowed_header(http::header::CONTENT_TYPE)
                    .max_age(3600)

            ).configure(test_routes)
```

Answer (score 0):

When your browser makes the request to your endpoint, it will send a 'pre-flight' CORS request before it sends your POST request to `/post`. This pre-flight request is sent with an OPTIONS method.

As you have configured your CORS headers as a response to your POST request, your browser never gets to see them.

You can see this behaviour in action if you open your browser dev tools while you make the request.

To ensure your CORS headers can be read by your browser, you would need to have a route on `/post` that expects an OPTIONS request, and this would return your CORS headers.

Rather than doing this manually, it is easier to use a library to handle this logic, for Actix Web, there is this: https://docs.rs/actix-cors/latest/actix_cors/#

Comment: thank you for you help, I have solved this problem